# Alamofire and GoogleMaps pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

How to use `use_frameworks!` for only one pod? Because when i past `use_frameworks!` into podfile, GoogleMaps don't work.
My podfile:

```
target ‘somename’ do

  #source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  platform :ios, ‘9.3’

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im' afraid you can't do it, according to this [feature request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839) and in fact is very reasonable, for example:

> **Transitive dependencies**:

If Pod A is build dynamically and depends on Pod B that is build statically and the app also depends on Pod B, it is for example impossible to build, because either Pod A will be missing the symbols of Pod B at link time, or you end up with multiple copies of Pod B.

And it's very sad that a library like Google Maps not has support yet for the directive `use_frameworks` that it's necessary to build pod in Swift. You can another libraries like [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) from Twitter.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to add Alamofire manually and it's works, though looks ugly.

Comment: Yes indeed, but manually you're avoiding all the benefits of use an dependency manager as Cocoapods. I don't know when Google is planning to update Google Maps, in my opinion it's loosing iOS consumers of it library, but...